# Assembly - Number of elements in register B HCS12

Tags: assembly, 68hc12

I've spent at least a week looking for references regarding this issue and I have to say I'm starting to give up. 
I can't seem to be able to find any notion regarding the number of elements in an array stored in register B on a HCS12. The memory address of this register is stored in register X.
The purpose is to find the number of elements to create a subroutine calculating the average of the elements of that array. 
I'd really appreciate any kind of help!

edit:
Corrected a mistake in my question

Comment: X is just a 16 bit register - it doesn't know anything about arrays. If it contains the address of an an array then it has no "knowledge" of how many elements there are in that array. It's up to the programmer to maintain this information. (You also mention register B in the title of your question - this is just an 8 bit accumulator - maybe this is where the number of elements is being passed to your subroutine though ?)

Comment: Sorry my bad. The array is stored in register B and the memory address is stored in register X. I should edit my question. 
So the point it to find the number of elements in the array in register B and loop through it to calculate the average

Comment: What you're saying is a bit inconsistent, but it sounds like you are already given the *number of elements* in B, so all you have to is iterate over all the elements in the array, summing them as you go, and then divide by B at the end to get the mean, no ?